# The data is not getting updated when integrating application insight with Power BI

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-application-insights

The data in powerbi is days old and I am connected to internet at all times. Is there a problem or is there any other way to integrate pbi with app insight?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely caused by the Dataset not refreshing. In Power BI, right click on the Application Insights dataset and select "Schedule Refresh". From here you can see a link to "Refresh history" and for a failure you have a link to the error.

A few questions:
1. What type of account are you using (Microsoft account like outlook.com) or AAD account (e.g. a corporate account in Azure Active Directory)?
2. What level of Power BI are you using - Free or Pro? (See https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/)
3. How often do you have refresh scheduled for?
4. Does a manual refresh of the dataset work successfully?

Thanks
Dale

Comment: 1. I am using a corporate account.
2. Power BI pricing tier is free.
3. I do a refresh just after sending the data from Application Insights. Though Why the data is not getting refreshed automatically.
4. No a manual refresh of the process does not work successfully. The data is I think 2 or 3 days old. and afterwards the data comes automatically but still not the current.

Comment: I have been refreshing the data continuously but sill the data is old.